# How to Count Total Rows in MongoDB with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, count

I'm working to count total rows, in case the column name is nama_materi with condition = "HTML".

Here's my code:

```html
getTotalListHTML: (req, res, next) => {
    modelsListMateris.find({nama_materi:'HTML'}, (err, result) => {
      if (result) res.send(result);
      else res.send(err);
    })
  },
```

I expect to add method count() after find statement, but it's not working. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongoose to get Count from a model

```
modelsListMateris.count({nama_materi:'HTML'}, (err, count) => {
        console.log( "Number of docs: ", count );
        if (count) res.send(count);
        else res.send(err);
    });
```

You can also use chaining functions like

```
modelsListMateris.find({nama_materi:'HTML'}).count(function(err, count){
    console.log("Number of docs: ", count );
    if (count) res.send(count);
    else res.send(err);
});
```

If you want rows with count you can use plugin **mongoose-paginate** and use it like this

```
 modelsListMateris.paginate({nama_materi:'HTML'}, {limit: 10, offset: 0})
```

Comment: your 2nd code is working but got an error 500 and still can't to get count from a model..

Answer (score 0):

I assume by rows you mean "documents".

Use the following mongo method:-

db.modelsListMateris.countDocuments( {nama_materi:'HTML'}, {} )

Comment: can't to use countDocuments method

Comment: the simply use count() method